# How to smoothly hide part of an element

Tags: css

I've a row of elements with some values in a container and its width is limited (eg 500px), but all of the elements takes more (eg 800px)

Using `overflow-x: hidden` it looks like: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/IPShow/tzua3dj0/7/)

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

#container {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container>* {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <section>2.43</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.17</section>
  <section>2.17</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.44</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.34</section>
  <section>2.35</section>
  <section>2.15</section>
  <section>3.10</section>
  <section>3.10</section>
  <section>3.10</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.34</section>
  <section>2.35</section>
  <section>2.15</section>
  <section>3.16</section>
  <section>1.10</section>
  <section>4.10</section>
</section>
```

But I want to see that (made in photoshop):

[image]

Is there a way to implement this smooth disappear without using `box-shadow`, because I'm going to crate a dynamic background?

Comment: you are probably looking for mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

#container {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* simply adjust the 40px to control the fading */
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(-90deg,#0000,#000 40px);
          mask:linear-gradient(-90deg,#0000,#000 40px);
}

#container>* {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <section>2.43</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.17</section>
  <section>2.17</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.44</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.34</section>
  <section>2.35</section>
  <section>2.15</section>
  <section>3.10</section>
  <section>3.10</section>
  <section>3.10</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.14</section>
  <section>2.34</section>
  <section>2.35</section>
  <section>2.15</section>
  <section>3.16</section>
  <section>1.10</section>
  <section>4.10</section>
</section>
```

Comment: [note for me]: Re-try finding the duplicate later

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the overflow hidden and can add some extra styles to do what do you want. 
To gain this, you need to add position relative to the section and then use these css,

```
#container {
  position: relative:
}

#container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
  );
  z-index: 2;
}
```

This is the output I got
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVfUt.png)

For the whole thing, you can follow this [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/naimur-rahman-fullstack/pen/ExWQNoL)